# Using Python Split and Strip Commands to reorder sting

Tags: python, split, strip

I have the string:

`aaa = "09/22/81,   John,  Paycheck  ,Lawrence,  Kansas,  556  :23:7895"`

I want to use the Python Split and Strip commands to reorder the list so that the list outputs:

```
Month,Day,Year, FirstName, LastName, City, State, first3socialsecurity, middle2socialsecurity, last4socialsecurity
```

Without any leading or trailing blanks basically, just reorder the sting using these methods.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `''.join(map(str.strip, aaa.split()))` but in future, _please_, add to your question also an attempt, thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to use `split` and `strip`? `aaa.replace(' ', '')` should be sufficient?

Comment: @mozway Individual values may contain whitespace in the middle.

Comment: Looks like you added your attempt as an answer that you subsequently deleted. You should [edit] your question if you want to add more details. Also remember to ask a _specific_ question. How did your approach fail to meet your expectations? Asking the right question is the first step of the [research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953) you must do before [asking](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953) on SO, and if you couldn't find an answer, remember to _ask that specific question!_

Answer (score 2):

I would use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) for this task as this gives more flexibility:

##### using only comma as final separators

```
import re
','.join(map(str.strip, re.split('[,:]', aaa)))
```

output: `'09/22/81,John,Pay Check,Lawrence,Kansas,556,23,7895'`

##### keeping the original separators

```
import re
''.join(map(str.strip, re.split('([,:])', aaa)))
```

output: `'09/22/81,John,Pay Check,Lawrence,Kansas,556:23:7895'`

used input: `aaa = "09/22/81,   John,  Pay Check  ,Lawrence,  Kansas,  556  :23:7895"`

Answer (score 0):

The [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method is not particularly well suited for this use case since there are multiple delimiters and `split()` accepts only a single delimiter. [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) would be better. But it can be done with `split()` by replacing all the alternate delimiters and normalizing them, so long as you don't expect those alternate delimiters to be used as valid characters in the other data values.

```py
data = "09/22/81,   John,  Paycheck  ,Lawrence,  Kansas,  556  :23:7895"

# Normalize to use a single delimiter -- , (comma)
normalized_data = data.replace("/", ",").replace(":", ",")

# Split on normalized delimiter and remove leading and trailing whitespace
values = [s.strip() for s in normalized_data.split(",")]

# Output new values delimited with a comma
print(",".join(values))
```

This could all also be done in a single one-liner

```py
print(",".join([s.strip() for s in data.replace("/", ",").replace(":", ",").split(",")]))
```